# What has 'rm -r ~' done to my home directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

gedit creates hidden backup files ending with '~'. I wanted to do a recursive cleanup of my directory tree.

The command `rm *~` will delete all local files ending with '~'

I thought `rm -r *~ .` would delete all files in the whole tree, but I typo-ed `rm -r ~`.

There was a message some directory could not be deleted and I quit the command. The question is: What have I been deleting?

I did notice that my Filezilla configuration was gone. Does this command delete all hidden directories from the home dir?

Comment: Well, at least I have a backup strategy... No real harm done.

Comment: Good to know; I have a policy of never using `-r` unless I want to get rid of everything.

Comment: As a side note, `rm -r *~ .` would delete all files and folders (in the current directory) matching `*~` or `.`. (`.` would be ignored by `rm` as a special exception, as most people don't want to recursively delete the current directory. The `*~` deletes all files and dirs in the current dir that end in `~`, but *not* files and directories in subdirectories of the current directory.) So that's not what you would have wanted. You would probably have wanted to use `find` with the `-exec` flag to recursively look through the directory tree and *non-recursively* delete each file ending in `~`.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I guess so, but find with -exec is always a hassle. Restoring the home dir is more of a hassle, though :-)

Comment: Informational: sing the `~` character without escaping it (like this: `\~`) will make Bash, ZSH, etc. (the `rm` command basically) think you mean the home directory.

Comment: @GUIJunkie Perhaps there is a graphical utility (or at least a prewritten script) for this and related purposes. A new [software-recommendation] question about that might be productive.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I remember on a forum/ML a while back, someone renamed `rm` and aliased it a script that warned/previewed/somesuch whenever `-r` was used.

Comment: When trying something doggy like this, it doesn't hurt to use rm -i the first time.  It will ask you about each file which is tedious, but safe.

Comment: @izx there have been very long discussions about using an alias such as rm='rm -i' which does what you suggest.  The upshot is that it gets you used to being safe and when you go somewhere else where that's not defined, it's not pretty.  Same goes for redefining anything that's already there.  It also produces unexpected behavior when someone else (possibly helping you) uses your system.

Comment: Oh man, I've been there... It's the day I learned I should really make backups. As an aside (too small for an answer), I've since had `rm` aliased to `rm -v`. In the case of mishaps, this will make me realize quickly something's wrong so I can `^C`, and it provides me with a log of what exactly I managed to delete, instead of having to guess.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### You have deleted (almost) all of your home directory!

`rm -r something` *recursively* deletes files and directories in/under *something*; it will only fail on items it does not have permission to delete, either because they are owned by a different user (e.g. `root`), or because they are in use (e.g. a GVFS mount).

If you did not add `-f` (as in, `rm -rf something`), you would get something like:

```
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘something’?
rm: descend into write-protected directory ‘something’?
```

At this point you can abort and you then likely realise that you executed the wrong command.

#### Suggestions from the community on how to avoid such accidents

> *Note: Community wiki, everyone please feel free to contribute.*

- For a few files, use the `-i` option to get a confirmation on removing files or directories:

  ```
  $ rm -ri something/
  rm: remove regular file ‘something/file~’? y
  rm: descend into directory ‘something’? y
  rm: remove regular file ‘something/file’? y
  rm: remove directory ‘something’? y
  ```
- If removing from a current directory, prefix it by a `./` to avoid mistakingly removing a different location.:

  ```
  $ cd something
  $ rm -v ./*~
  removed ‘./file~’
  ```

  The above was for demonstrating the use of `./`. If there is a subdirectory, you can of course use `rm -v something/*~` as well. **Beware**: do not think that `rm ./.*` removes all hidden files in the current directory. See [this Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/q/211690/51929) for workarounds on hidden files globbing.
- **Move rather than delete:** Rather than deleting files recursively in the first place I got used to [move](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mv.1.html) the files I want to get rid of somewhere else before I delete them finally. If something went wrong its easy to restore.

  ```
  mv -b SOURCE DEST
  ```
- **Use `find` (possibly with `grep`) to *preview* if you want to recursively delete selected files.**  You should try to make this a rare occurrence, but if you have to...

  1. `find` with no arguments recursively lists all files/directories under the current one. You should try to look up `man find` on how to make it selective (a treasure trove), but if you don't want to bother, you can just use the familiar `grep` to filter for the files you want to delete.
  2. Suppose I'm an uber-l33t kernel hacker, and am bothered by the few KBs of "example" files in my source tree; I want to delete all files containing that in the name. So I type `find | grep example`, which gives me [these 20 files.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1065766/)  That looks good, so I now go and delete those exact files, along with the `rm -v` verbose output previously mentioned, via `xargs`:

     ```
     find | grep example | xargs rm -v
     ```

     which gives me [this output.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1065768/)   Such previewing prevents problems where say, you make a typo and type `sample` instead of `example`.

The above solution should not be used if you may have filenames containing spaces, tab characters, newlines, or quotes (`"` or `'`), as this will lead `xargs` to either fail, or feed `rm` with incomplete filenames, which in worst case could end up removing the wrong files. The safe way to do the above is to do it all with `find`'s operators and actions.

The following will show all files that contain the word `example`

```
find . -name "*example*"
```

If that list is the files you want to remove, use the `-exec` action to pass the files to `rm`.

```
find . -name "*example*" -exec rm -v {} +
```

See [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for more help with using `find`.

Comment: piping `find` output to `grep` and `xargs rm` is dangerous.

Comment: Ubuntu is not Windows, you can still remove a file even if it is being read/written. However, if the file permissions are restrictive (i.e. read-only), you'd get a confirmation request. Also, the `rm` command has a `-v` (verbose) option which shows files being removed and `-i` to always get a confirmation.

Comment: @izx I added some extra details, you may want to include something about quoting and using `find`.

Comment: @izx: added `mv` (my favourite command) ;)

Comment: I'd at least add an example of using `find` the safe way, one that doesn't break (and potentially delete the wrong files) if filenames contain space, tab, newline, `"` or `'` characters. E.g. `find . -name "*example*" -exec rm -v {} +`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: @geirha: why is `find -delete` so dangerous? I would have said something here but I don't know other than it recently found and wiped my `/` despite a dry run without option `-delete` only found few files that I wanted to remove. I see that you recommend `-exec rm` instead.

Comment: @Takkat `-delete` is not dangerous, and you can safely use it instead of `-exec rm {} +`. I generally prefer to use standard tools and features when possible. `-delete` is a non-standard, GNU extension to `find`, so it'll work fine on Ubuntu, but may not on other systems.

Comment: Instead of moving with `mv`, if you have an XDG trashcan, you could use `trash` from [trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. An unquoted tilde character as a separate argument gets expanded to your homedir. So `rm -r ~` got expanded to `rm -r /home/yourusename`. So you told rm to recursively delete all files in your homedir.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion for more about how tilde expansion works.