# How do I allow a standard user to update the kernel modules for VMware?

Tags: sudo, virtualization, vmware, users

I've set up VMWare Player for my wife. Every once in a while (notably after a kernel update), the VMWare Player needs to be compiled into the kernel.

My spouse does not have su- activated (if anybody screws up the OS, [it's going to be me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157513/what-has-rm-r-done-to-my-home-directory)). I'd like to give her permission to do this, but only for that program.

Is this possible? Can it be done safely (for the OS)? How can it be done?

**Edit:** I tried to add the following to visudo

> guijunkette ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vmware-modconfig

When running with her user, after typing her password, the following error occurred:
[image: Error]

So, in the end, no cigar.

**Edit:** I've given up on VMWare Player and moved to VirtualBox. Made a clean install.

Comment: So...did it work?

Comment: @izx, didn't work so far. See my edit.

Comment: Looking at the meta-problem - rebuilding a module on kernel upgrades: this sounds like a perfect job for dkms - the modules would be rebuilt when a new kernel is installed (rather than having to do it manually). Also, I see that there's a `open-vm-dkms` package - maybe this does what you need?

Comment: @JeremyKerr, so, how would you go about that? Just a sudo apt-get install open-vm-dkms, sit back and relax?

Comment: @GUIJunkie, yeah, I'd give that a go :)

Comment: @JeremyKerr, OK, it's installed, now what should I do?

Comment: @GUIJunkie: i'm no expert on that package, sorry :/ I expect that it would have built & installed the vmware guest kernel module. If not, you might need an `sudo update-dkms`.

Comment: OK, I'll do that next time.

Comment: GJ: please see edited answer. It appears to be very difficult to get the internal upgrade to work because of how VMWare Player performs sudo authentication.

Comment: @JeremyKerr: open-vm-dkms won't work here because it's only for VMWare (Tools on) guests, not hosts...

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** If you want VMWare Player to perform the update automatically, I don't think it's possible via `sudoers`; that's because **VMWare uses its *own* graphical sudo front-end to check if the user has unrestricted sudo privileges...**
>
> A trace shows that this is how the GUI update is called when you start VMWare Player and it detects a new kernel:
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-gksu --sudo-mode --message=Please enter your password to proceed. '/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig' --icon='vmware-player' --appname='VMware' --gcc='/usr/bin/gcc' --headers='/lib/modules/3.2.0-27-generic/build/include'
> ```
>
> As you've already tried, even simply adding `/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig` doesn't work.

We'll assume your spouse's username is *guijunkette*. The script to manage the VMWare kernel modules is `/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig`; in light of the note above, it's best to explicitly invoke this from the terminal; to make life easier for your wife, I have included a desktop shortcut so that she needn't even open the terminal.

1. `sudo visudo`
2. Around line 25, below the line `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, insert:

   ```
   guijunkette  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
   ```
3. Exit the editor

To rebuild the modules, she can now run `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` without being asked for a password.

#### Desktop Shortcut

What you can do is create the following desktop file in your wife's `~/Desktop` folder, and whenever VMWare Player flashes the "You must..." message, ask her to click Cancel, run this shortcut, and then start VMware Player (successfully) again:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Update VMWare Modules
GenericName=VMWare Updater
Comment=Update VMWare modules for a new kernel (console mode)
Exec=sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
Terminal=true
Icon=/usr/lib/vmware/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/actions/vm-upload.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

Paste this into, e.g. `/home/guijunkette/Desktop/vmwareupdater.desktop`, and remember to `chmod +x` it.

Here's a demo:

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: I've made the change to the visudo file, even though I can't find the config-tools at /usr/bin/. I'm hoping that file gets created when needed.

Comment: @GUIJunkie: Sorry, I made a mistake in giving you the VMWare tools command instead of vmware-modconfig. Please see edits, including the recommended way to invoke a module rebuild.

Comment: I'll try that first thing in the morning :-)

Comment: Regarding security, specifying the allowed command-line arguments prevents privilege escalation (for example, by specifying an arbitrary program to run as `root` with the `--gcc` flag). But the problem is that you generally only have to build kernel modules *when there is a new kernel version*. This will work once, but it will never work again. It's necessary instead to allow `--headers=...` arguments specifying headers in `/lib/modules`, but not others. I'm not sure `sudo` can be configured to do this.

Comment: I keep on getting the same error, with -- headers and --headers alike.

Comment: Also, I noticed that it should be /lib/modules/3.2.0-27-generic instead of -26, but the result is the same... :-(

Comment: @GUIJunkie: how are you running it -- and getting the GUI error? Please try the `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` option instead -- run from the terminal.

Comment: @EliahKagan: it's `--`, thanks. Normally `vmware-modconfig` is smart enough to figure out the paths, so I don't seem to understand how GUIJunkie is running his upgrades and getting that explicit path -- if it's something run implicitly from Player, it may be difficult to get it to sudo.

Comment: I'm doing it naively like my wife would... from the Launcher.

Comment: For this kernel update, I've already compiled VM, so next time I'll give that a try, or do you suppose `open-vm-dkms` takes care of it now?

Comment: @GUIJunkie: `open-vm-dkms` **won't** work because it's only for VMWare *guests*, not hosts: `open-vm-dkms - Source for VMware guest systems driver (DKMS)`

Comment: @GUIJunkie: since it looks like there's no way to make the VMWare internal sudo work, and open-vm-dkms is only for guests on vmware, we're left with the CLI upgrade method outlined in the answer. Would you please consider awarding it the bounty?

Comment: @izx, thanks for your time and dedication. I'll keep you posted on developments.

Comment: If I create a batch to first update and then launch VMPlayer, can I add a shortcut to the launcher? This way it would be completely transparent for my wife.

Comment: @GUIJunkie: yes, it would; a shell script is a good idea. Give me a little bit of time to find the console command that won't rebuild unless a new kernel is detected -- I believe `install-all` force-rebuilds every time?